# CordovaModuleLoadError [ '4.3.0' ] - multi device hybird app in visual studio

Tags: ios, cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

This is a follow up question after I attempted to fix [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493886/error-cordovamoduleloaderror-multi-device-hybird-app-in-visual-studio).

I now have Visual Studio 2015 with the associated tools for Apache Cordova, but I am still unable to run multi device hybrid app in ios simulator.

I created a new blank Cordova project and I am able to run it on the Ripple browser simulator. However, when I try to run the app on the configured Mac to test it on ios I get the following error:

```
Done building 1630 : error CordovaModuleLoadError [ '4.3.0' ]
```

And here is the full terminal output:

```
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ vs-mda-remote --secure false

vs-mda-remote

Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

0.2.11



Loading resources for language en from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/resources/en/resources.json

Build Retention initialized with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds, maxBuildsToKeep 20

Initialized BuildManager with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 1629

Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000

ios-sim is installed on path at: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release/ios-sim



New build request submitted:

/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=debug

{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',

  host: '192.168.1.11:3000',

  connection: 'keep-alive',

  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }

New build request submitted for cordovaVersion: 4.3.0; buildCommand: build; configuration: debug

Build will be executed under: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630

Saving build request payload to : /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630

Saved upload to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/upload_1630.tgz

Extracting /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/upload_1630.tgz to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/cordovaApp...

POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=debug 202 427ms - 521b

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 4ms - 521b

Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/cordovaApp. Requesting build.

Taking 1630 as current build

Building cordova app BlankCordovaApp2015Test at appDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/cordovaApp

Opened build log file /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/1630/build.log

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 22ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 0ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 9ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 0ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 0ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 2ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.09kb

Done building 1630 : error CordovaModuleLoadError [ '4.3.0' ]

Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.

GET /build/tasks/1630 200 1ms - 4.12kb

GET /build/tasks/1630/log 200 3ms
```

I have also tried the solution of changing the ownership of npm directory [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913021/vs-mad-remote-build-failed-with-error-cordovamoduleloaderror-4-1-2) which did not work for me. Here is the output in the terminal when I tried to resolve the issue following the solution in the previous link:

```
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ ls
HideMeService            idevicecrashreport        ideviceinstaller        iproxy
asn1Coding            idevicedate            idevicename            node
asn1Decoding            idevicedebug            idevicenotificationproxy    npm
asn1Parser            idevicedebugserverproxy        idevicepair            plistutil
brew                idevicediagnostics        ideviceprovision        vs-mda-remote
idevice_id            ideviceenterrecovery        idevicescreenshot        zipcmp
idevicebackup            ideviceimagemounter        idevicesyslog            zipmerge
idevicebackup2            ideviceinfo            ios_webkit_debug_proxy        ziptorrent
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ ls -l
total 70672
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root              wheel     24308 Sep  1  2014 HideMeService
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 asn1Coding -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Coding
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        39 May 26 19:30 asn1Decoding -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Decoding
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 asn1Parser -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Parser
-rwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin       791 May 26 19:30 brew
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        47 May 26 19:30 idevice_id -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevice_id
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        50 May 26 19:30 idevicebackup -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicebackup
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        51 May 26 19:30 idevicebackup2 -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicebackup2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 idevicecrashreport -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicecrashreport
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicedate -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedate
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        49 May 26 19:30 idevicedebug -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedebug
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        60 May 26 19:30 idevicedebugserverproxy -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedebugserverproxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 idevicediagnostics -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicediagnostics
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        57 May 26 19:30 ideviceenterrecovery -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceenterrecovery
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        56 May 26 19:30 ideviceimagemounter -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceimagemounter
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 ideviceinfo -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceinfo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 ideviceinstaller -> ../Cellar/ideviceinstaller/1.1.0_1/bin/ideviceinstaller
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicename -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicename
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        61 May 26 19:30 idevicenotificationproxy -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicenotificationproxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicepair -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicepair
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        53 May 26 19:30 ideviceprovision -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceprovision
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        54 May 26 19:30 idevicescreenshot -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicescreenshot
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        50 May 26 19:30 idevicesyslog -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicesyslog
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        65 May 26 19:30 ios_webkit_debug_proxy -> ../Cellar/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/1.4_2/bin/ios_webkit_debug_proxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        35 May 26 19:30 iproxy -> ../Cellar/usbmuxd/1.0.10/bin/iproxy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root              admin  36032800 May 23 06:13 node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  wheel        38 May 25 18:15 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 plistutil -> ../Cellar/libplist/1.12/bin/plistutil
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root              wheel        51 May 26 19:25 vs-mda-remote -> ../lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/bin/vs-mda-remote
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        34 May 26 19:30 zipcmp -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/zipcmp
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        36 May 26 19:30 zipmerge -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/zipmerge
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        38 May 26 19:30 ziptorrent -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/ziptorrent
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ sudo npm cache clear
Password:
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ sudo chown -R `whoami` npm
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/npm
chown: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/npm: No such file or directory
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ ls -l
total 70672
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root              wheel     24308 Sep  1  2014 HideMeService
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 asn1Coding -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Coding
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        39 May 26 19:30 asn1Decoding -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Decoding
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 asn1Parser -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5/bin/asn1Parser
-rwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin       791 May 26 19:30 brew
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        47 May 26 19:30 idevice_id -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevice_id
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        50 May 26 19:30 idevicebackup -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicebackup
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        51 May 26 19:30 idevicebackup2 -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicebackup2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 idevicecrashreport -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicecrashreport
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicedate -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedate
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        49 May 26 19:30 idevicedebug -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedebug
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        60 May 26 19:30 idevicedebugserverproxy -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicedebugserverproxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 idevicediagnostics -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicediagnostics
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        57 May 26 19:30 ideviceenterrecovery -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceenterrecovery
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        56 May 26 19:30 ideviceimagemounter -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceimagemounter
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 ideviceinfo -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceinfo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        55 May 26 19:30 ideviceinstaller -> ../Cellar/ideviceinstaller/1.1.0_1/bin/ideviceinstaller
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicename -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicename
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        61 May 26 19:30 idevicenotificationproxy -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicenotificationproxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        48 May 26 19:30 idevicepair -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicepair
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        53 May 26 19:30 ideviceprovision -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/ideviceprovision
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        54 May 26 19:30 idevicescreenshot -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicescreenshot
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        50 May 26 19:30 idevicesyslog -> ../Cellar/libimobiledevice/1.2.0/bin/idevicesyslog
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        65 May 26 19:30 ios_webkit_debug_proxy -> ../Cellar/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/1.4_2/bin/ios_webkit_debug_proxy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        35 May 26 19:30 iproxy -> ../Cellar/usbmuxd/1.0.10/bin/iproxy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root              admin  36032800 May 23 06:13 node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  wheel        38 May 25 18:15 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        37 May 26 19:30 plistutil -> ../Cellar/libplist/1.12/bin/plistutil
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root              wheel        51 May 26 19:25 vs-mda-remote -> ../lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/bin/vs-mda-remote
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        34 May 26 19:30 zipcmp -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/zipcmp
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        36 May 26 19:30 zipmerge -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/zipmerge
lrwxr-xr-x  1 IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN  admin        38 May 26 19:30 ziptorrent -> ../Cellar/libzip/0.11.2/bin/ziptorrent
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$
```

Comment: The dot is important before ".npm" here.  See if typing "sudo chown -R whoami ~/.npm" (with the dot before npm) resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my specific issue resolved by reinstalling ALL tools for iOS as [mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054%28v=vs.140%29.aspx#ios). Now, Visual Studio will successfully launch the iPhone simulator on the connected Mac device with my Cordova app in it.

However, when I try to

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm`

or

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

I am still getting 'No such file or directory' for some reason. Here is the full terminal output:

```
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
chown: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.npm: No such file or directory
IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:bin IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
chown: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.npm: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913021/vs-mad-remote-build-failed-with-error-cordovamoduleloaderror-4-1-2) suggests, can you try running

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

(note the "." before npm)
or

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
```

Let us know if that doesn't resolve your problem

Comment: "sudo chown -R whoami ~/.npm" => chown: whoami: illegal user name **&** "sudo chown -R IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN ~/.npm" => chown: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/.npm: No such file or directory **&** "sudo chown -R IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN /usr/local/bin/npm" => no error but still getting the same error "error CordovaModuleLoadError [ '4.3.0' ]"

Comment: Ahh - That was a problem with the way stack formats things.  It's sudo chown -R \`whoami\` ~/.npm - You should also be able to use sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm.

Comment: What version of node are you on?  Type "node --version" Next, what does "npm config get cache" and "npm config get prefix" return?

Comment: I am still getting the no such file or directory error. Please refer to this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xjDQtHTT) for all the command output.